# Handling eTags on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, etag

Any idea how to handle eTags at client side? We are planning to use eTags with images in our application which are coming from the server.

For what is eTag please see this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Answer (score 7):

Starting points for your study ...

**NSMutableURLRequest**

Here you can set eTag value for you request.

```
[self addValue:eTag forHTTPHeaderField:@"If-None-Match"];
```

This request is usable with NSURLConnection.

**NSURLConnectionDelegate**

Delegate of your NSURLConnection has method ...

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

... where response in your case is `NSHTTPURLResponse`.

You should check response statusCode in another delegate's method ...

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

... status code 304 is received when remote object is not modified. If remote object is modified and eTag is supported, you can find it in `[response allHeaderFields]`.

Comment: I would disagree on checkin the the status code in `-connectionDidFinishLoading:`. You might as well check it as soon as the response arrives, so the connection can be immediately cancelled or otherwise handled in the event that the code is unexpected