# iOS: HTTP headers: Etag missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-headers, etag

When I make a URL request, the response headers doesn't contain an Etag value. How can I get an Etag? I'm trying to set up to do Conditional Get Requests so that I can determine when there is new updates to a webpage.

Thanks!
Sandy

Comment: You may get something from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026278/handling-etags-on-iphone

Comment: @Alex I know that once I get the initial eTag that I have to add and If-None-Match to my url request to test for the conditional get. My problem is when I make my first Get Request (the initial one) to get the first eTag value of the page -- the eTag doesn't exist in the header... so there is nothing there. In order to set up Conditional Get, I have to store the Etag value and the Last Modified date value of the first Get request.